# Generate meaningful image description based on image labels

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Currently me and three of my friends are working on a project to generate an image description based on the objects in that particular image (When an image is given to the system novel description has to be generated based on the objects and relationship among them). So simply one person is planning to identify objects in the image and label them using a Fast Regional based CNN (FRCNN). In my part I have to implement a meaningful description based on those image labels (Output of the FRCNN is planning to take as the input to my RNN) by considering the relationship among them.

Currently I'm planning to implement a Recurrent neural network (RNN) to generate the description. but however I have a doubt that whether is it possible to generate a description using an RNN when it is just given set of words (Image label names) as an input. since RNNs are mainly used for use cases which have sequences and if I just give label names will it be able to generate a description by considering the relationship among them ?

If not can anyone please tell me what would be the best way to implement this ?

PS: I'm very new to machine learning and hope to get a clear idea to come to a better solution.

Comment: This is called Image Captioning, have you read any of the state of the art papers about it?

Comment: yeah I have read several research articles. One that got most of my attention is Andrej Karpathy's research on "Deep Visual-Semantic Alignments for Generating Image Descriptions". But the problem I have is whether a RNN is capable of generating a description based only on the label names. In many research papers they use a CNN to extract features and embed that feature set (last hidden layer) with trained language model into a common embedded modal to generate a description.

Comment: Problem I have is I can't give the output of the last hidden layer of the FRCNN to my RNN. because the person who is implementing the FRCNN need to output identified objects to the user. As I know using a CNN identified objects can be accquired only through the final layer of the CNN. So if we remove that last layer of the CNN then that person can't output the identified objects. Am I correct ?

Comment: In that case you must introduce an intermediate representation between FRCNN and your RNN. You just need to encode the right information.

Comment: So you mean I have to save the extracted features from the FRCNN and provide that into my RNN ? Sorry I didn't understand your solution properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am also learning RNN right now. And I believe from one single image, it is possible to generate one sentence to describe it, if the image is meaningful.

I will share you some material that I think it is helpful

https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjf_pKusPLUAhUTrRQKHQjMAlcQFgg2MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcs224d.stanford.edu%2Freports%2Fmsoh.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHqAkpk6haw87Cx3X23TDjRBFN6aA

Comment: Thanks Yirui. yeah I think it is possible to generate description from a single image. but for that we need a CNN or any suitable way to extract the image features no ? Actually I have elaborated my problem little more in the 2 comments above. Do you think it is possible to generate the description using a RNN with the problem I have ?